# Como verificar sem dentro de uma #id tem uma .class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tem um topo `#header` que adiciona a class `.hide-bar` quando scroll mas ao voltar ao topo, esse classe some.

Como verificar com ***jQuery*** se está `class` está presente nesta `id` ou não? Preciso dessa verificação para sumir/voltar com determinados blocos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar o método [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) do jQuery assim:

```
if($('#header').hasClass('hide-bar')){
    // fazer algo caso tenha a classe
}
```

Eu costumo evitar jQuery sempre que possivel em funcionalidades simples como essa. Para fazer isso com JavaScript nativo pode fazer assim:

```
var elemento = document.getElementById('header');
if(elemento.className.indexOf('hide-bar') != -1){
    // fazer algo caso tenha a classe
}
```

Ou usando JavaScript em browsers modernos (IE9+):

```
var elemento = document.getElementById('header');
if(elemento.classList.contains('hide-bar')1){
    // fazer algo caso tenha a classe
}
```